# Complex postgres query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Currently having a query for filter with parameters `premium_amount_lower_range, premium_amount_upper_range, application_date_lower_range, application_date_upper_range, insurance_type_id`

```
@filtered_quotes = current_user.insurance_subscribers.includes(:insurance_types).includes(:insurance_subscribers_types, :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers).
                   premium_amount(params[:dashboard][:premium_amount_lower_range], params[:dashboard][:premium_amount_upper_range]).
                   duration(params[:dashboard][:application_date_lower_range], params[:dashboard][:application_date_upper_range]).
                   insurance_type(params[:dashboard][:insurance_type_id])
```

But Now need to filter according to their status also. Having problem with it.
I have status column in `insurance_subscribers` and `insurance_subscribers_types_carriers` tables, both columns are enum.

I tried to add where clause like

```
@filtered_quotes = current_user.insurance_subscribers.includes(:insurance_types).includes(:insurance_subscribers_types, :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers).
               where("insurance_subscribers_types_carriers.status = 1")
#              ...
```

This is giving me error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "insurance_subscribers_types_carriers"`

but when i try to do like

```
@filtered_quotes = current_user.insurance_subscribers.includes(:insurance_types).includes(:insurance_subscribers_types, :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers).
           where(status: 1)
#          ....
```

This will put the where clause on insurance_subscribers.

Trying to add a simple where clause `WHERE insurance_subscribers_types_carriers.status = 1` in above query but Having so much trouble with this query.

Associations

insurance_subscriber.rb

```
has_many :insurance_subscribers_types, dependent: :destroy
has_many :insurance_types, through: :insurance_subscribers_types
has_many :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers, through: :insurance_subscribers_types
```

insurance_types.rb

```
has_many :insurance_subscribers, through: :insurance_subscribers_types
has_many :insurance_subscribers_types
has_many :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers
```

insurance_subscriber_type.rb

```
belongs_to :insurance_subscriber
belongs_to :insurance_type
has_many :carriers, through: :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers
has_many :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers, dependent: :destroy
```

insurance_subscribers_types_carrier.rb

```
belongs_to :carrier
belongs_to :insurance_subscribers_type
```

Comment: What is the relation between `insurance _types`, `insurance_subscribers` and `insurance_subscribers_type_carriers`? Please add all the associations

Comment: Added Associations

Comment: Have you try left outer joins manually instead of includes?

Comment: Not yet, but I will try and let you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add `queries` across associated models, first you need to join them. Since you have `has_may :through` associations, you can accomplish want you want as follows:

```
InsuranceSubscriber.joins(insurance_subscriber_types: :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers)
.includes(:insurance_types, :insurance_subscribers_types, :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers)
.where("insurance_subscribers_types_carriers.status = ?", 1)
```

As you see, you can join and reference your associations, even you have `has_many :through` associations as follows `joins(.joins(insurance_subscriber_types: :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers)`.

You will get sql an output as follows:

```
InsuranceSubscriber Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "insurance_subscribers".* FROM 
"insurance_subscribers" INNER JOIN "insurance_subscriber_types" ON 
"insurance_subscriber_types"."insurance_subscriber_id" = 
"insurance_subscribers"."id" INNER JOIN "insurance_subscribers_types_carriers" ON 
"insurance_subscribers_types_carriers"."insurance_subscriber_type_id" = 
"insurance_subscriber_types"."id" WHERE (insurance_subscribers_types_carriers.status = 1)
```

I replicated and tested your question with models structure, like these:

**PS: I made small changes in your model names, so be careful. They were so confusing try to simplify them.**

insurance_subscriber.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: insurance_subscribers
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  status     :integer          default("0")
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class InsuranceSubscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :insurance_subscriber_types, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :insurance_types, through: :insurance_subscriber_types
  has_many :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers, through:     :insurance_subscriber_types

  enum status: {active: 0, passive: 1}
end
```

insurance_subscriber_types.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: insurance_subscriber_types
#
#  id                      :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                    :string
#  insurance_subscriber_id :integer
#  insurance_type_id       :integer
#  created_at              :datetime         not null
#  updated_at              :datetime         not null
#

class InsuranceSubscriberType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :insurance_subscriber
  belongs_to :insurance_type

  has_many :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :carriers, through: :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers
end
```

insurance_subscribers_types_carriers.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: insurance_subscribers_types_carriers
#
#  id                           :integer          not null, primary key
#  carrier_id                   :integer
#  insurance_subscriber_type_id :integer
#  status                       :integer          default("0")
#  created_at                   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at                   :datetime         not null
#

class InsuranceSubscribersTypesCarrier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :carrier
  belongs_to :insurance_subscriber_type

  enum status: {active: 0, passive: 1}
end
```

insurance_types.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: insurance_types
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class InsuranceType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers
  has_many :insurance_subscribers_types_carriers
  has_many :insurance_subscribers, through: :insurance_subscribers_types
end
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out : ))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the included association (insurance_subscribers_types_carriers) in the query you have to add "references" otherwise insurance_subscribers_types_carriers will be loaded separately from the main query:

```
InsuranceSubscriber.includes(:insurance_subscribers_types_carriers)
               .where("insurance_subscribers_types_carriers.status = ?", 1)
               .references(:insurance_subscribers_types_carriers)
```